# Correct way to update bulk data. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-table, model, insert-update

### Explanation

I have an ASP.NET MVC application where a user can update data displayed in a table. The table has a column with input boxes and another column with checkboxes where data can be edited and then updated.

### Issue

The issue I'm encountering is when I edit the table, and then submit the data to the method within the Controller, the model parameter is always null. Hopefully the below code will describe the issue better.

### Needing Advice

The table can potentially have more than 1000+ rows. Is there a way to detect changes to the edited row, and only update the changed rows accordingly, without having to update all the records?

### Vehicle Model

```
public string VEHICLE_NAME { get; set; }
public string VEHICLE_MAKE { get; set; }
public string VEHICLE_MODEL { get; set; }
public Nullable<bool> IS_NEW { get; set; }
```

### EditController

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateTable(List<Vehicle> vehicle)  <==vehicle is always null 
{
  //left out for brevity
}
```

### Edit View

```
@using PagedList.Mvc;   <==imported asp.net paging namespace for the table
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Vehicle>


@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateTable", "Edit", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Vehicle name</th>
                <th>Vehicle make</th>
                <th>Vehicle model</th>
                <th>Is New?</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
       <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.VEHICLE_NAME)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.VEHICLE_MAKE)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => item.VEHICLE_MODEL)</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk" checked="@(item.IS_NEW)" /></td>
                </tr>

            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    //submit button
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Comment: I would consider wrapping each row in a form with its own button, and then use AJAX to perform the update so that the user doesn't lose their place as a result of a full post back.

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't part of the requirements that I have. There needs to be one button, which saves 1 or more edited data.